# Unable to download podcast after iTunes previously crashed while downloading it

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I subscribe to a podcast with weekly episodes.

While downloading one episode of the podcast, iTunes crashed. Now I cannot download that episode anymore - if I try to, it errors with the (!) symbol next to it. I can download any other episode of the podcast without issues.

I tried to unsubscribe from the podcast and re-subscribe, hoping it would fix the problem. But I still cannot download that episode.

Any ideas how I can make iTunes forget about the failed download and let me get that episode again?

Answer (score 1):

Go to folder where you store podcast episodes you've subcribed to. (By default it's something like "itunes" folder in "mymusic" folder).

Search for folder named "Downloads". That folder is used for storing temporary files while downloading particulary episode, and it should be empty.

If ITunes crashes, some parts of the episode remain in this folder and that's causing the problem you encountered. If happens that there are some folders or files with .tmp extension, delete them and then try again to download particular episode.

Comment: I checked the "Downloads" folder and there are no files in there (I am showing hidden files too).